# How to refresh Power View sheet connected to a Tabular Model after making changes on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, tabular, powerview

SOLVED: apparently this was due to a connection issue w my tabular model. I had to rebuild all of my existing tabular model connections to get everything to refresh properly.

I'm currently working with a power view excel sheet that's connected to a tabular model. I know that the sheet can be easily refreshed if it's linked to power pivot in excel, but I'm having a hard time getting my power view sheet to refresh after making changes in my tabular model. The only method I've found is to

(1) redeploy the tabular model in visual studio/sql server data tools
(2) open a new power view sheet and reconnect to the newest version of the deployed model

This is tedious and headache inducing. Is there a faster method for this? Can I

(a) get my power view sheet to reflect the changes in my tabular model (field list, data, etc) without redeploying it?
(b) refresh the data/field list on my current power view sheet without having to open another sheet and reconnected to my newly deployed model?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say you are having a hard time getting the power view to refresh what you do you mean? Are you getting an error?
If you have redeployed the model and have removed or renamed a field that was used in a chart then power view will remove it from that chart. It won't detect that it was renamed. You will have to add the field in again manually.

Comment: @Rory I mean that the power view won't reflect the changes in my tabular model (ex: new column, type change, new tables, etc). Every time I redeploy the model, the existing connection is lost and my power view sheet stops working.

Comment: Close the workbook and reopen. Then from the Power View menu choose Refresh.